# Swift button animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

```
func rotateY(){

    if let TransformAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform"){

        TransformAnim.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
        TransformAnim.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 1, 0))

        TransformAnim.cumulative = true
        TransformAnim.duration = 3
        TransformAnim.repeatCount = 2

        self.caRotateBtn.layer.addAnimation(TransformAnim, forKey: nil)

}
```

The button animation above is weird in Swift the button rotates in weird way.
But in Objective-C the code runs right. Why ? Can someone help ?

```
- (IBAction)YRotateAction:(id)sender
{
    CABasicAnimation *TransformAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

TransformAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
TransformAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0)];

TransformAnim.cumulative = YES; TransformAnim.duration = 3; TransformAnim.repeatCount = 2;

[self.caRotateBtn.layer addAnimation:TransformAnim forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: I think you should do something about it… Maybe it’s smart to describe the “weird” behaviour, “weird” doesn’t really help with… well… anything at all

Comment: The rotation of the button is not the right way it is like only half of the button is rotating and the other half disappeared during that time. Try running the code.

Comment: I copied/pasted both of your examples each into its own project, respectively, and I witnessed identical behavior in both, and both appeared to completely rotate the button in its entirety. Do you perhaps have a complex view hierarchy, or a constraint issue? I simply put a button in the scene, centered vertically and horizontally, and there was no "weird" behavior for me. Some more context may be helpful, if you can.

Comment: Yes I i figured out. The problem was an UIImageView that is why I only saw half of the button. But I don't know how can I fix this problem because I need my background image and I don't want to remove it.